# does anybody knows a good currency widget for ubuntu 14.10

Tags: software-recommendation, widgets

I would like to use an easy and small currency widget on ubuntu 14.10. Pref. one that can be minimized near the power, system settings and network bar.
Does anybody knows a good one?
I am enjoying a lot with ubuntu, although I am still a beginner after 1 years.

Answer (score 1):

**Ubuntu Software Center** has only one Currency Converter and it only converts to and from Euro: **KEuroCalc**

But you can also use a multi-feature calculator like **Qalculate** to do the job (although it can only be added to Unity Launcher, and not the Top Panel or SysTray.

The application downloads the **latest currency rates**, and then  all you need is to type in something like **GBP 1 to USD** and press **Enter** to convert.

More info here: http://www.maketecheasier.com/qalculate-powerful-calculator-for-linux